# How to extract from two tables and join them like the example

Tags: sql, union

```
   Table A     .............................  Table B    
+-----------+  .........................+-----------+   
|Id |   Sum1|  .........................|Id   |Sum2 |    
| 1 |  1500 |  .........................|  1  | 2300|         
| 1 |  2500 |  .........................|  1  | 1500|  
| 1 |  1300 |  .........................+-----------+   
+-----------+
```

I have Table A and Table B. I need query to result like this:

Result

```
    +-----------------------+  
    |Id |   Sum1|   |Sum2   |    
    | 1 |  1500 |   |......0|         
    | 1 |  2500 |   |......0|  
    | 1 |  1300 |   |......0|  
    | 1 |  0....|   | 2300  |  
    | 1 |  0....|   | 1500  |  
    +-----------------------+
```

I need to filter with id and the result should be like the third table where I can divide left and right column from Table A and Table B. 
Please help. I tried with other examples but I didn't succeed.

Comment: You want to divide left and right columns in the third table? I can tell you the answer now: 0, and undefined. I'm not sure what you are trying to do here at all.

Comment: i need just like the result to give me all same id, and depends if the sum1 has value then sum2 is null and if sum2 has value then sum1 is null. I need this for my project so the user see this result. Just like the answer

Comment: All your id values are `1`, this is not a very helpful example. Do you want to join results from `Table A` and `Table B` with the same id, or just append results from both tables? Please edit to clarify.

Comment: I just want to join the results from Tabe A and Table B with the same Id. I have more than 1 id in the tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want that output, you can use:

```
SELECT ID, Sum1, 0 AS Sum2
FROM TableA

UNION ALL

SELECT ID, 0 AS Sum1, Sum2
FROM TableB
```

Not sure why it would be a useful resultset, though ...

Comment: it works, it is ussefull for filtering when i have more fields with different id and when i want to filter only with let's say id=1 it give me the result only for id=1, so that way i have what i need. Thank you